# How I can wait until a Win32 ThreadPool is finished with work, with external cancellation?

Tags: c++, winapi, threadpool

I'm trying to use a ThreadPool in my program and I have a question.

I need to have an external stop - in the past, a function callback is used to check external stop, and now I must do the same.

In the new ThreadPool API, I can use `CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers()` and wait for all queued jobs, or cancel pending jobs and wait for executing. But if I call `CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers()` and wait for all, I can't do something on an external event.

What is a good way to wait on all jobs without calling this, or the similar blocking functions?

I think, I can do this with a counter of jobs - completed and queued, but maybe there are another good solution?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would push "thread calculation finished" and "external event" messages onto a single thread-safe queue. Then the main thread can continuously loop through the queue and handle events off of it.

```
enum EventType {
    THREAD_CALCULATION_FINISHED,
    EXTERNAL_EVENT
};

// you could probably use an atomic-op ring buffer instead
std::queue<EventType> message_queue;
std::mutex message_queue_mutex;

// ...

void wait_on_thread_pool() {
    bool stopped = false;
    int thread_counter = NUM_THREADS;
    while (!stopped) {
        message_queue_mutex.lock();
        while (!message_queue.empty()) {
            EventType e_type = message_queue.front();
            message_queue.pop();
            switch (e_type) {
            case THREAD_CALCULATION_FINISHED:
                --thread_counter;
                if (thread_counter == 0) {
                    stopped = true;
                }
                break;
            case EXTERNAL_EVENT:
                stopped = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        message_queue_mutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aww, no [lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution: using of thread-save list with tasks, and `SubmitThreadpoolJob` in every added element in list. In this case you can clean task list on external stop and use another cancelation function.